# Datanucleus enhancer error: no objectid-class

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

I have the below domain model class

```
@Entity @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class MyBean {

     @Id @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;

     ...

     @Transient
     public String getOther() {
          ...
     }
}
```

Running DataNucleus Enhancer gives the following error:
Class MyBean has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.

Why?

Comment: really? I can enhance that exact class with no problem at all. Perhaps there is something you're not telling us ...

Comment: I believe they had the wrong class import for @Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the `@Transient` annotation on the method. Removing it solved the issue.

Still, in this case, taking into account the @Access and @Id annotation on a field, the @Transient annotation should be ignored. Or, preferably, the error message should be improved.

Comment: As I said 'Or'. And now I added preferably.